# Designing of a 2:1 multiplexer for 64 bit input and output

Tags: verilog

How to design a 2:1 mux for a 64 bit input and output using Verilog code?

Comment: Is it a homework assignment? Or you want someone to do your job for you?

Comment: Lack of own effort.

Answer (score 3):

/// sel is 1 bit.  in_a, in_b and out are 64-bit vectors

```
if (sel) begin
  out = in_a;
else
  out = in_b;
end
```

///

Comment: or `out = sel ? in_a : in_b;`

Comment: But don't we have to define the size for the inputs?

Comment: @PrashmitaDey Why would you want to work with Verilog if you do not how to do even most basic things?

Comment: @PrashmitaDey  of course.  Check out http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/mux.html